# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.Contract.EmotionScores[]' to 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Emotion.Contract.Scores[]'

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to run the sample app. It worked once and after that one time I keep getting the error in the title in the following code line in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
EmotionScores = emotions.Select(e => e.Scores).ToArray()
```

What can I do ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get is pretty self-explanatory. You try to assign a reference to an array of `Scores` to a variable that can holds a reference to an array of `EmotionScores`. This cannot be done, because as it seems there isn't any implicit conversion between these types.

If just want to get and save somewhere the scores, you could just store them in another variable:

```
var scores = emotions.Select(e => e.Scores).ToArray();
```

Comment: I was confused because this isn't my code, it's Microsoft's code and it should work, as it did in my first try, after the first try I didn't change anything. I don't just need to save to scores somewhere, this initialises an EmotionScores that makes the app work.

Comment: This sounds a bit awkward. When you say it's Microsoft code, you mean apparently that is code that has been written by Microsoft, but don't you have access to the definition of `Score` and `EmotionScore`? If the answer is yes, then you can spot the issue by cheking their definitions. If not I thing the odds aren't with you. Furthermore, if you have the definitions, please share it with us by posting them in your question. Thanks

Comment: The thing is, everything works great for a couple of times and later it simply doesn't works and throws this error without changing anything in the code.