# An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?

Tags: api, azure-cognitive-services, emotion

I am getting the following error:

```
An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?
```

Why is this?

[image: an explicit conversion exists]

```
private async void getEmotion_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                emotionResult = await emotionServiceClient.RecognizeAsync(imageStream.AsStream());
                if(emotionResult != null)
                {
                    Scores score = emotionResult[0].Scores; 
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Output.Text = "Error returning the Emotion";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to a similar question, answered here: [Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.Contract.EmotionScores[]' to 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Emotion.Contract.Scores[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039572/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-microsoft-projectoxford-common-contract-emotions)

Scores and EmotionScores are the same object name-wise but not cannot be converted automatically.  You can either say

```
EmotionScores scores = emotionResult[0].Scores;
```

or simply

```
var scores = emotionResult[0].Scores;
```